# Django Foreign Key difficulty

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I wrote the following model in Django, and wanted to define a foreign key to a class which is declared below the first class. Eclipse is showing an error. How to do it  ?

```
class address_type(models.Model):
 address_type_desc = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class customer_address(models.Model):
 address_type_code = models.ForeignKey(address_type, related_name='type_of_address')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually have an error, but you can use quotes:

```
class AddressType(models.Model):
 address_type_desc = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class CustomerAddress(models.Model):
 address_type_code = models.ForeignKey('AddressType', related_name='type_of_address')
```

I have also edited your class names to conform to the norm in Python. You should read [pep-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official style guide for Python.

Comment: What difference does it make to use single quites..apart from this ?

Comment: Quotes come in handy when you define the foreign key class _after_ the class linking to it. Since Python code is executed in the order it is written; there will be an error because your linked class would not have been instantiated.